# Why ggplot cannot build bubble xy-plot with size proportional to frequency of points in xy bin? Or how to make it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I broke my neck trying to build an xy-plot with bubbles, which sizes depend on frequency/density of datapoints with xy coordinates of this bubble (or xy coordinate ranges for this bubble).

```
# example of data
  d <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,1,2,2), y=c(1,1,2,3,2,3))

# chart form ggplot2 book, that has xy-coordinates and size, 
# but size is a duplicate of y-coordinate
  ggplot(d, aes(x)) + 
  stat_bin(aes(size = ..density..), binwidth = 0.1, geom = "point", position="identity")

# most close result I got with density. 
# But this density2d: 
# 1) put geoms where there is no data points and 
# 2) not ONE bubble for bin
  ggplot(data=d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  stat_density2d(geom="point", aes(size = ..density.., alpha=..density..), contour=F)
```

I have seen solutions with prior data transformations, that is creating data.frame with all possible pairs of xy-cooordinates listed in 2 columns and frequency count in extra column.
But that is not aesthetic, not flexible and may require a lot of space in my case.

Comment: are you looking for `stat_sum()` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34019600/show-bigger-dots-when-same-values-are-plotted/34027650#34027650

Comment: please check the answer here       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702027/some-changes-in-a-bubbleplot-ggplot/28710598#28710598

Comment: @Samehmagd that solution requires prior data transformation (aggregation), that I have had to avoid